# jQuery addClass/Mouse-over timeout combo issue

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-ui

The block of code below works perfectly until I added mouse over timeout. The mouse-over time out works but the classes are no longer being added. Is there a way to combine both and still have the classes added as supposed?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myTimeout;
$('#nav-bar > ul li').mouseenter(function() {
    myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $('.drop-down-plates:visible').hide();  
    $('#nav-bar ul li.current-menu-item').removeClass('current-menu-item');
    $('#nav-bar ul li').eq($(this).index()).addClass('current-dmenu-item');
    $('.drop-down-plates').eq($(this).index()).slideDown();
    $('#nav-bar ul li.current-dmenu-item').removeClass('current-dmenu-item');
    }, 200);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
});


 $('#drop-down-box').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.drop-down-plates:visible').slideUp();   
    $('#nav-bar ul li.current-dmenu-item').removeClass('current-dmenu-item');   
});



});
```

Comment: Where is the block of code?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the timeout,  `this` will not be the element you hovered inside. You can get around this by caching the context in a variable outside the template.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var myTimeout, 
  $('#nav-bar > ul li').mouseenter(function() {
     $this = $(this); // save reference to the element
     myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
     $('.drop-down-plates:visible').hide();  
     $('#nav-bar ul li.current-menu-item').removeClass('current-menu-item');
     $('#nav-bar ul li').eq($this.index()).addClass('current-dmenu-item');
     $('.drop-down-plates').eq($this.index()).slideDown();
     $('#nav-bar ul li.current-dmenu-item').removeClass('current-dmenu-item');
     }, 200);
  }).mouseleave(function() {
     clearTimeout(myTimeout);
  });
  $('#drop-down-box').mouseleave(function(){
     $('.drop-down-plates:visible').slideUp();   
     $('#nav-bar ul li.current-dmenu-item').removeClass('current-dmenu-item');   
  });
});
```

---

In this case you can just save the index of the hovered element outside the hovered element as well. Since you seems to be using it only for finding the index.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to help. I did exactly what you said and it still doesn't add the Classes.

Comment: Can you share the html and css as well..?